# Why does WiFi work with WICD but not Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, wicd

So my WiFi can connect with WICD, but not the default KDE network manager. I would like to know why. Do both these applications handle the connection differently? If so what would the difference be?

My hardware is a Broadcom 4313. I've tried the STA drivers and the open source drivers, and a few other options with Network Manager. None of which worked. In fact, everything was working fine for a while, just that one day, it didn't. I can't identify what i did to trigger this issue though.

And to be more specific: Even with network manager, I could connect to open connections (the ones without a password), I can connect to WPA connections, just not to one particular WEP.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove network-manager to get wicd to work, or vise-versa. Both the network-manager and wicd can not work together. Please refer this URL: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

> You must remove network-manager to get wicd to work. Check to see if
>   network-manager is installed and see if, after you installed the
>   driver, your wireless is already working in the notification area of
>   your desktop manager. You may already be good to go.
>
> wicd (Wireless Interface Connection Daemon) is a lightweight
>   alternative to NetworkManager. It is environment-independent, making
>   it suitable for all desktop environments, including GNOME, Xfce, LXDE,
>   and Fluxbox. Like NetworkManager, wicd is configured via a graphical
>   interface. Your wireless interface should not be referenced within
>   Ubuntu/Debian's /etc/network/interfaces file.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not come with Broadcom support. To start off, connect via Ethernet cable and open terminal. Run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade b43-fwcutter
```

ask a question if you have an error!